# C# & DevExpress : Unbound column not display value correctly after assigned

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have this unbound column :

```
bandedGridColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
bandedGridColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit     = false;
```

And i'm assigning value for this column in CustomUnboundColumnData :

```
private void vwVD_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "UnitOfMeasureName" && e.IsGetData)
    {
        e.Value = UnitOfMeasureName;
        vwVD.RefreshData();
    }
}
```

The problem is the Column does not display data simultaneously, i have to click to the column's cell to make it display value correctly, any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: In your code you have an `UnitOfMeasureName` variable (`e.Value = UnitOfMeasureName`). It seems that problem is in this variable. What value is contained in this variable?

Comment: @nempoBu4 with all respects, that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the vwVD.RefreshData() method call from the CustomUnboundColumnData event handler.  This method should not be called here.  Also, please make certain that the column's FieldName property is set a unique value between other columns and there is no column with such field name in the DataSource.

Comment: i added it in effort to make the column to display the new value !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following example on devexpress forum would be helpful to you:

> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2442

Comment: Thanks Ruchi, unfortunately, this doesn't help me in my case